# When I use pd.get_dummies on a categorical column with three regions, it creates three new binary columns. How can I fix this

Tags: pandas, label-encoding

df=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['sex','smoker','region'], drop_first=True)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbAr9.png)

I just wanted to expect not seeing three seperated columns but it is impossible.What is your suggestion?I attached image

Comment: So what did you expect? Also please provide a [mre], not images